# Powerset without subset with more than k elements

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, terminology

I am looking for something very similar to the powerset concept but i don't know how to search for it. This is what I found:

Wikipedia defines the powerset as follow:

> In mathematics, the power set (or powerset) of any set S is the set of
>   all subsets of S, including the empty set and S itself.

And provides this example: the powerset of {x, y, z} is
{{}, {x}, {y}, {z}, {x, y}, {x, z}, {y, z}, {x, y, z}}

I am looking for an algorithm that given the number of elements `n` of a set and the max number of elements in the subsets `k` can return the powerset of a given set except the empty set and except all the subsets with more than `k` elements.

Does that set have a name? I mean, how do you call such a set (or the algorithm that produces it)?

Comment: Have you tried to come up with such an algorithm?

Comment: yes, it is trivial to code but I need to know how that set is called because I have to write a technical document. I asked for the algorithm because if that set has no a name, i would like to have a algorithm name, a concept name or something that I can google for.

Comment: I would be surprised if this set had a particular name. If you are writing a technical document, I recommend clearly defining what you are talking about, because even if this set has a standard name it is likely not commonly known enough that you can assume your readers are familiar with it.